# What is Salesforce Integration Tab and Salesforce.com Status in Email Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect, email-studio

Can anyone explain the below topic with a real-time example :

1. Email Studio > Admin > Salesforce Integration Tab

[image]

2. Email Studio > Admin > My User > Click on any User > Salesforce.com Status

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first example that you are providing is showing that the Marketing Cloud account is successfully integrated with a Salesforce Org via Marketing Cloud Connect.

The second example is showing that that specific Marketing Cloud user is not integrated with a corresponding Salesforce user.

When Marketing Cloud Connect is set up between Marketing Cloud and Salesforce CRM, you also must integrate users to be able to access and utilize data across both Clouds. As the second example is not integrated, you would want to follow the Knowledge Article below to connect:

Connect your Marketing Cloud user with your Salesforce user
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000354555&type=1

For more information on Marketing Cloud Connect in general, please refer to the documentation below:

Marketing Cloud Connect
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5

Connect the Clouds with Marketing Cloud Connect
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_connect_the_clouds.htm&type=5